# How to compile sass while npm start?

Tags: npm, sass, nodemon, node-sass

i want to compile sass to css while my npm is starting, but i dont found any way to do this with just 1 script, like:

```
"start": "nodemon ./bin/www & node-sass --watch scss -o public/stylesheets"
```

Do you know any other way to accomplish this task?

Here's my app.js:

```
app.use(sassMiddleware({
    src: path.join(__dirname, 'scss'),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed',
    prefix:  '/stylesheets'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The watch command doesn't compile anything till the first change. You need to call the compile with first